# Writing bash script to reboot pi 10 times and log output

Tags: python, bash, cron, reboot, python-2.x

I have written a Python script and scheduled it to run @reboot using cronjob. Sometimes this script throws an exception sometimes it works perfectly. I want to write test scripts for this.

Preferably, rebooting Pi 10 times and logging all the output in a log file. I have tried running a bash script, but it resets to zero after pi reboot for the first time.

Comment: what resets to zero?

Answer (score 1):

How are you keeping track of how many times you've booted?

You'll probably need to save the count in a file.

```
[[ -s boot_count ]] || echo "0" > boot_count
n=$(cat boot_count)
(( n += 1 ))
echo "$n" > boot_count
(( n < 10 )) && reboot
```